# Reading registers or thread local variables of another thread

Tags: c, linux, x86-64

Is it possible to read the registers or thread local variables of another thread directly, that is, without requiring to go to the kernel? What is the best way to do so?

Comment: [ptrace](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace)?

Comment: I need a fast solution, ptrace is too slow. And by the way ptrace does require going to the kernel.

Comment: David: Because I want to put the variables in a location which is fastest to access, which the registers are, as you never deal with a cache miss when you put something in a register. However, I also need to read the values from other threads.

Comment: OK, well your assumption is just wrong. Registers are fastest to access locally, but slowest to access from another core because there's no direct way to access them. Part of the reason memory is "slower" is that the machine's memory architecture does all the work of synchronizing memory between cores/cpus for you...

Comment: BTW with your most recent comment in mind, I doubt my answer is useful to you (just stop trying to do what you're trying to do -- it's a wrong approach) but it answers the question as written...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't read the registers, which wouldn't be useful anyway. But *reading* thread local variables from another thread is easily possible.

Depending on the architecture (e. g. strong memory ordering like on x86_64) you can safely do it even *without* synchronization, provided that the read value doesn't affect in any way the thread is belongs to. A scenario would be displaying a thread local counter or similar.

Specifically in linux on x86_64 as you tagged, you could to it like that:

```
// A thread local variable. GCC extension, but since C++11 actually part of C++
__thread int some_tl_var;

// The pointer to thread local. In itself NOT thread local, as it will be
// read from the outside world.
struct thread_data {
    int *psome_tl_var;
    ...
};

// the function started by pthread_create. THe pointer needs to be initialized
// here, and NOT when the storage for the objects used by the thread is allocated
// (otherwise it would point to the thread local of the controlling thread)
void thread_run(void* pdata) {
    pdata->psome_tl_var = &some_tl_var;

    // Now do some work...
    // ...
}

void start_threads() {
    ...
    thread_data other_thread_data[NTHREADS];
    for (int i=0; i<NTHREADS; ++i) {
        pthread_create(pthreadid, NULL, thread_run, &other_thread_data[i]);       
    }

    // Now you can access each some_tl_var as
    int value = *(other_thread_data[i].psome_tl_var);
    ...
}
```

I used similar for displaying some statistics about worker threads. It is even easier in C++, if you create objects around your threads, just make the pointer to the thread local a field in your thread class and access is with a member function.

Disclaimer: This is non portable, but it works on x86_64, linux, gcc and may work on other platforms too.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do it without involving the kernel, and in fact I don't think it could be meaningful to read them anyway without some sort of synchronization. If you don't want to use `ptrace` (which is ugly and non-portable) you could instead choose one of the realtime signals to use for a "send me your registers/TLS" message. The rough idea is:

1. Lock a global mutex for the request.
2. Store the information on what data you want (e.g. a `pthread_key_t` or a special value meaning registers) from the thread in global variables.
3. Signal the target thread with `pthread_kill`.
4. In the signal handler (which should have been installed with `sigaction` and `SA_SIGINFO`) use the third `void *` argument to the signal handler (which really points to a `ucontext_t`) to copy that `ucontext_t` to the global variable used to communicate back to the requesting thread. This will give it all the register values, and a lot more. Note that TLS is a bit more tricky since `pthread_getspecific` is not async-signal-safe and technically not legal to run in this context...but it probably works in practice.
5. The signal handler posts a semaphore (this is the ONLY async-signal-safe synchronization function offered by POSIX) indicating to the requesting thread that it's done, and returns.
6. The requesting thread finishes by waiting on the semaphore, then reads the data and unlocks the request mutex.

Note that this will involve at least 1 transition to kernelspace (`pthread_kill`) in the requesting thread (and maybe another in `sem_wait`), and 1-3 in the target thread (1 for returning from the signal handler, one for entering the signal handler if it was not already sleeping in kernelspace, and possibly one for `sem_post`). Still it's probably faster than mucking around with `ptrace` which is not designed for high-performance usage...

Comment: Ah, that is toooo slow for my purpose. I will stick with what I've been doing so far, that is, to use a global array.

Comment: @user1018562 A global array accessed from several threads may incur severe performance penalties because of cache synchronization, snooping etc.